# com.android.support:design with androidX (1.0.2)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, androidx, android-design-library

I want to use TextInputLayout inside my project, but I'm using androidX library

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2"

/*this don't work*/
implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"
```

This is the exception which I'm facing

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class

This error thrown when the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) tries to load a particular class and the specified class cannot be found in the classpath.

You should use

```
com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
```

**DEMO**

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >

   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

Comment: worked for me, thanks.